# Difference between three separate if statements and using 'or' in one if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say, for example, that there are three football teams whose players all need to sign in each day using a Python 3.x program shared between them.

Which of these would be more efficient/better and why?

This:

```
while True:
    team = input("Which team are you in? A, B or C?").lower()
    if team == "a" or team == "b" or team == "c":
        #asks for player's number and then registers him in for their team for the day
        break
    print("Invalid input. Please enter A, B or C.")
```

or this:

```
while True:
    team = input("Which team are you in? A, B or C?").lower()
    if team == "a":
        #asks for player's number and then registers him in for their team for the day
        break
    if team == "b":
        #asks for player's number and then registers him in for their team for the day
        break
    if team == "c":
        #asks for player's number and then registers him in for their team for the day
        break
    print("Invalid input. Please enter A, B or C.")
```

Comment: For your purpose, the first `if` statement is fair. The second style can be used if you have more definitions going with any of the conditions. But since in your question, all the conditions go with just `break`, the first if statement is more than enough.

Comment: The former is more commonly expressed `if team in ('a', 'b', 'c')`, or since strings are iterable, more concisely, `if team in 'abc'`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: It won't have any noticeable effect on performance no matter what you choose. Your else is redundant and your elif's could as well be if's

Comment: @Padriac I understand that the elif's could be if's, but why is the else redundant? It's  for the purpose of validation (so that the user is asked the question again).

Comment: @BobZeBuilder, what happens if a user enters a,b or c?

Comment: @Padriac They'll be signed in for the day for their team.

Comment: I mean in the code, if you break how could you also get to the next print line? You either leave the loop or stay in it, you cannot do both

Comment: If a user enters 'a', 'b' or 'c', they won't see 'Invalid input. Please enter A, B or C.'.

Comment: Remove the else and enter "a" in your code and see what happens, having the print at the indentation same level as the if. The logic is exactly the same as why you can replace the elif 's with if's

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I've changed it.

Comment: It is the same as having  `return foo else:return bar`, the else is redundant as you can only return either foo or bar not both

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I tried `if team in 'abc'`, but if the user enters 'abc', that works, but I want it to be invalid. I only want the user to be able to enter 'a', 'b' or 'c' (uppercase is valid too). How can I do that?

Comment: @BobZeBuilder, if you only think of efficiency, then the second process is better than the first one. Because in the first process the three conditions are checked whatever the input is. But for the second process if input is **a** it checks only one condition and two for **b** and three for **c**. But in this case the efficiency does not matter as test cases are very small.

Comment: @BobZeBuilder Use the "longer" `if team in ('a', 'b', 'c')` version to avoid also catching `'ab'`, `'abc'`, and various other substrings. Commonly if case doesn't matter the user's input is simply cast to another case ("normalized"). `if team.lower() in ('a', 'b', 'c')` or `if team.upper() in ('A', 'B', 'C')`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Okay, but I already did `.lower()` at the end of `team = input("Which team are you in? A, B or C?").lower()`. There's no difference in performance or anything if I do `.lower()` immediately when input is taken, is there (except for `.lower()` not affecting `team` in your case)?

Comment: @BobZeBuilder You're right. I just didn't reread the question before making my 2nd comment. No difference when you call lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that when you use separate `if` statement for your conditions you would be able to follow an special code block (commands) based on that condition, while if you put all of the conditions on one `if` statement you have to use same commands for all of them.

So it's all depends on your logic, and there is not difference in terms of performance. if you want to follow an specific command for all of the conditions you better to chain the conditions with boolean operators. Otherwise you should use separate `if` statements for each condition and follow the related commands for each condition.

Comment: Ah, I thought there might be some other differences (possibly to do with efficiency or something).

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is better because it's easier to read. The second approach would be better if you needed to do different checks per team. Since you are writing separate ifs you have more flexibility.

In terms of efficiency it really maters what you would do inside the if statement afterwards. E.g. if in the first case you test if team in ('a', 'b', 'c') and when true, you search again in a list to find the exact variables to work on, whereas in the second case since you know the exact team you don't need to search and process those variables directly, then the second approach will be more efficient.

To get the best of both, clean approach that searches only once you could write something like this:

```
team_objects = {  # Or db search instead
    'a': team_a,
    'b': team_b,
    'c': team_c,
}

letter = input('Which team are you in? A, B or C?').lower()
team = team_objects.get(letter, None)
if team:
    team.players += 1  # or something else
else:
    print('Invalid input. Please enter A, B or C.')
```

Answer (score 0):

if Efficient/better means which way runs faster and you concern the performance of your code, you can write a simple benchmark to test it in your case. You can calculate the elapsed time between two time points. For example checking 100K times for a random `team` value.

From my own perspective, I think we should write more readable code, makes the code much easier to be understood by other programmers, it may not speed up your developing, but it will not delay your project for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is concise and right for only obtaining valid input. The second one is when there is some preprocessing to do for each valid input **before actually using the input**, as you are still in the `while True` loop. You can make the 1st one cleaner,

```
options = ("a", "b", "c")
while True:
    option = input("x: ")
    if option in options:
        break
```